# What Python 3 version for my Django project

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I will try to port my Python 2.7 with Django to Python 3. But now my question is what version is the most stable one today? I've heard people use 3.2 and 3.4 and recommend it. But now I'm asking you guys.

What version is the most stable one today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to [their downloads page](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/), you will find the following statement (my emphasis):

> We recommend using the **latest version** of Python 3 [...]

I've been using Python 3.4.3+ in a Django 1.8.2 project without issues and I don't see why you should run into problems here.

However, if you *do* run into issues, you should file a bug.

> What version is the most stable one today?

Whatever version shows up as the recommended download in the python homepage should be considered stable. If that happens to be v3.5, then you should use that.

Answer (score 0):

Python's version are quite stable, but you have to check is virtualenv on your OS is handled already by particular Python's version eg. 3.5.0 is not yet prepared for it. I recommend you 3.4.x, which I use on my own without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You may check for 'What Python version can I use with Django?' in official documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/faq/install/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/) faq which lists which Python version is supported to which Django version