# Django project - 1.4 to 1.8?

Tags: python, django

I'm taking over somebody else's project that was coded using `Django 1.4` and `Python 2.6`. Pretty old, i know.

I want to upgrade it to `Django 1.8` and `Python 2.7`.
After installing `Python 2.7` and `Django 1.8` (using `pip`), i noticed that the project itself didn't change and it's still "set" to work with `Django 1.4` and `Python 2.6`.

What is the process i have to go through to make that kind of upgrade?

Comment: While you are at it, why don't you update to Python 3? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981738/what-python-3-version-for-my-django-project?pagesize=50

Comment: And Django 1.11, the current LTS release. 1.8 isn't supported anymore.

Comment: Does the project use a virtualenv?

Comment: No it doesn't..

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/upgrade-version/

Comment: Is the project using any libraries specific to py2.7?  I'm with the rest. Upgrade now before you incure development debt for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `virtualenv` would be one easy way to fix this problem.

Without `virtualenv`, you would also need to change the default python for the system (varies by OS flavor) or call `manage.py` by explicitly specifying the python interpreter:

```
python2.7 manage.py [options...]
```

You might also need to delete the previous django installation if you simply installed a new one and didn't "upgrade".

Steps to do this using `virtualenv`:

```
virtualenv env27 --python=python2.7
source env27/bin/activate
echo "Django==1.11" >> requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
./manage.py
```

Comment: What is the process of taking a folder containing a `Django` project and "make it work" with the updated versions of `Python` and `Django` using `virtualenv`?

Comment: Added the steps. You could've just done `pip install Django` from within virtualenv (after activating) but it's always good to specify a version in the requirements file so that future updates to accidentally introduce breaking changes.

Comment: Ok thanks! What does the last line do? (I'm pretty new to `Django` as well)

Comment: `./manage.py` runs django, so to speak. For instance, `./manage.py help` would show the list of available django commands, such as "testserver" to start the django backend server in debug mode.

Comment: Ok. Also - does my django app project folder needs to be inside of the `virtualenv` folder or outside of it?

Comment: the two are not related and can be inside one another, or separate. I like to keep them separate.